What does "out" mean here?

She spent up until her early 30's in restaurants. Started serving, moved up to management and eventually out to run banquets and whatnot at a golf course near us.


Please quote the source. The paragraph doesn't look right.

Restaurants are often in towns or cities, and golf courses are usually out of them.

The text looks like badly transcribed informal conversation.

This is a very important question for learners. Please...I guess many d.v.ers don't really get how English works. Of course, out is lower case.

This is a very important question for learners. Please...I guess many d.v.ers don't really get how English works. "out" is lower case, here. I just wonder who is downvoting all my answers, which, by the way, go a long way to explaining very common spoken English forms.

It's a metaphoric movement out of the restaurant business proper, into banquet catering at a customer's premises. Not literally out of the restaurant.

@FumbleFingers That figurative sense is a possibility but so is the locative sense  because of "at a golf course near us".   The locatve sense being "away from here" not the sense of "exiting".

I was a latrine cleaner and then moved out into motivational speaking. Now I'm a billionaire. My book Ditch That Brush tells my story. $19.99 inc delivery.

@TimR: That's a trivial distinction where strictly speaking both interpretations can apply (and in practice it makes zero difference to the meaning of the containing utterance). It's not helpful to tell learners they should care whether out is literal or figurative there. Besides, most likely Lambie is perfectly correct in assuming the OP's difficulties stem from failing to recognize the deleted predictable repetition of the verb, not the exact sense of moved out [to do something else].

@FumbleFingers   Yes, my lord. Tell me what is helpful for learners. Answer some questions, dude, instead of lurking in the comments area.

That sounds like colloquial conversational American English, punctuation issues aside.  "out" means "out (on catering assignments) at the golf course", not in the restaurant.   out can mean "in a  location away from this vicinity (but not in the direction of its 'gravitational' center, i.e. not in the direction of a larger place that it belongs to)". It is deictic, expressing the point-of-view of the speaker. The distance from "this vicinity" could be large or relatively small.
A person living on the east coast of the US might say of someone who is now 2,000 miles away:

Our former neighbor got a job offer in Colorado and now lives out west.

Or a person living in the suburbs of a city might refer to someone who lives 20 or 30 miles further away from the city like this:

They live out in the boondocks.

Your example, with punctuation:

She spent up until her early 30's in restaurants. Started serving, moved up to management, and eventually out to run banquets and whatnot at a golf course near us.


I have an American friend spent several college vacations working as a waitress and bar person at golf courses in California. They had big 'clubhouses' where many members spent more time than they did playing golf on the actual course. Mainly eating, drinking, socialising, and schmoozing.

Yes, such clubhouses are  a usual feature of golf courses, unless the course is a municipal one.

running banquets is not catering. You can be the person in charge of the company who runs banquets and "receives" the stuff catered at a banquet hall. And you overlooked the double preposition with the same action verb, which is a typical feature of all Englishes.

I didn't overlook the fact that "move" was supplemented by two prepositional phrases. I just understand "out" to mean "away from here" rather than your more specific "leaving this company's employ".     Some caterers run banquets, handling food, setup, serving, and cleanup, and others just provide the food.  If it's an in-house position, she might arrange for the food.  Dedicated In-house catering.

No, you overlooked the fact that an action verb and using two different prepositions without repeating the main verb is very common in English.

I didn't miss anything about the "action verb".  I simply treated "out" as meaning "away from here" and you're treating the "here" that is implicit in the deictic sense of "out'" as "in this company" and "out" as "for another company".  The lack of repetition of the verb is irrelevant to my answer.

Hey guys, you're both making good points. Please don't shoot each other!

This is an somewhat quirky but good example of using one verb (move),  with two different prepositions: up and out or on:
Examples:

He moved up in the company and then on to another one.

He joined the company in 1990 as a salesman, then he moved up into management and eventually out to another company as director.


move up can be used on its own. move out can be used on its own. You don't need to repeat the main verb move as shown in the example above. This is common with action verbs and prepositions.
Another action verb: fly down and over.

The pilot flew down through the clouds and then over to the airport.

This usage is not limited to American English.
Let's look at a British English example with the action verb pop:
to pop over [go somewhere] and to pop down.

The young man popped over to the house and then down to the riverbank.

In the OP's example, this works the same way, despite the subject of the sentence not being used by the speaker. That does happen in colloquial speech:

[She] Started serving, moved up to management and eventually out to run banquets and whatnot at a golf course near us.

Why out: Because she moved "out" of the company's premises to run banquets somewhere else. move out is often used to say to leave the place where you live. In this case and my second example above, to leave a place to go elsewhere.
Yes, this is conversation, colloquial English but it contains a very important teaching point about using action verbs once with more than one preposition!

You need to support your contention that "move out" has the meaning "to leave a company to take employment elsewhere". Please cite some examples of that.

You also need to say why the locative use isn't viable,  that "out" there means "leaving this company's employ" rather than referring to the location of the golf course relative to the speaker's  location.

@TimR  I think my explanation is enough.

I'm sure you do.

That downvote is ridiculous! We don't need to cite dictionaries to prove that move on / out / up / over / across / down / ... are all perfectly valid "metaphoric" usages (where in almost all cases the preposition is optional anyway, and contributes little to the overall meaning).

@FumbleFingers Thank you, Sir! :) But please see my main point about one action verb and two preps in the same utterance.

@FumbleFingers But Lambie is not treating it figuratively: "Why out: Because she moved "out" of the company's premises to run banquets somewhere else. move out is often used to say to leave the place where you live."   [my emphasis]

@MariosAthanasiouἝλλα Παιδάκι μου. Thanks. I upvoted  yours.
